# In my case what is the preferable way to persisting data in MVC5 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 app in for a particular view I am using a XML file to obtain the data. (Not by design)

On this view I load that data into a grid and through the grid there are several calls back from the view to the controller.

In this case is the best way to handle the data via the Session State or Data store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasource is irrelevant; each request should act as any other and retrieve the data from the datasource. If you want to improve performance for further requests, you can cache the result using `MemoryCache`, but using the session for this is absolutely the wrong way to go.